# Calling function from another scope

Tags: javascript

I have the following function in javascript:

```
function jsController() {
   this.foo = function() {
      $("body").click(function() {
         $(this).externalFunction(); 
      }
   };
   this.externalFunction = function() {
      alert('a');
   };
}
```

It however doesn't work, it says externalFunction() is undefined.

How can I solve this?

Comment: so you want to call the `externalFunction` that you have defined as `this.externalFunction` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in this case: `$(this).externalFunction()` the `this` object is scoped to the `$("body")` element. To solve it:

```
function jsController() {
   var self = this;
   this.foo = function() {
      $("body").click(function() {
         self.externalFunction(); 
      }
   };
   this.externalFunction = function() {
      alert('a');
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `.bind()` to solve this issue:

```
function jsController() {
  this.foo = function() {
    $("body").click(function() {
      this.externalFunction(); 
    }.bind(this))
  };
  this.externalFunction = function() {
    alert('a');
  };
}
```

or even like this:

```
function jsController() {
  this.foo = function() {
    $("body").click(this.externalFunction.bind(this))
  };
  this.externalFunction = function() {
    alert('a');
  };
}
```

see: [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)